# How to get new column headers and display indexes when you are reording the listview columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am stuck.
I want to get the new places of the columns when the user reorders (moves the columns by mouse) them. 
So far:

```
private void listView1_ColumnReordered(object sender, ColumnReorderedEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (ColumnHeader cHeader in listView1.Columns)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(cHeader.Text + cHeader.DisplayIndex.ToString());
   }
}
```

I have an event when the listview columns are reordered. 
However, the messagebox shows otherwise as the columns are recorded as what they were before the reordering.
I am very stuck. Can anyone help me? 
I just want to get the new placements of the columns and their display index when they are moved, not the previous configuration.

Comment: The `DisplayIndex` values are what they were before?

Comment: Hi, I have a 4 columns. Title, Name, Address, Age. Display indexes respectively: 0, 1, 2, 3. When reordering with the code above gives the same display indexes (when say Name should be 0, Title, 1, address 2, Age 3), then reordering again gives me those indexes (not the new ones) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListView.ColumnReordered` event is fired after the user reorders a column, but before the actual reordering of the column occurs.  You can also cancel the column reordering if you want by setting the `Cancel` property of the `ColumnReorderedEventArgs` argument to `true`.

Because the event is fired before the actual reordering takes place, you'll always get the previous column indexes when you're looking at the `DisplayIndex` property in your delegate for this event.  Look instead at the `OldDisplayIndex` and `NewDisplayIndex` of the `ColumnReorderedEventArgs` argument.  That will tell you the column's previous index and what the column's new index will be - if you don't cancel the event.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the event. I will use the NewDisplayIndex of the ColumnReorderedEventArgs argument.